# Filter SQL results with join from one to many table relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables that are connect via "NBR":

```
Process
```

[image: Process table]

```
Service
```

[image: Service table]

```
create table service(
DIV CHAR(4 BYTE),
PAID    CHAR(2 BYTE),
NBR CHAR(3 BYTE),
MODEL   CHAR(1 BYTE),
LINE    CHAR(1 BYTE),
YMD NUMBER(8,0)
);


create table process(
DIV CHAR(4 BYTE),
PAID    CHAR(2 BYTE),
NBR CHAR(3 BYTE),
BANK    CHAR(2 BYTE),
UNIT    CHAR(2 BYTE),
CAR CHAR(2 BYTE)
);



INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('555', '1',    'NY',   'AR91', '6',    20240311);
INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('555', '2',    'NY',   'AR91', '6',    20240311);
INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('555', '3',    'NY',   'ZZ1',  '6',    20240311);
INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('556', '1',    'NY',   'AR10', '8',    20240311);
INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('556', '2',    'NY',   'ZZ1',  '8',    20240311);
INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('557', '1',    'NY',   'AR10', '9',    20240311);
INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('600', '1',    'NY',   'ZZ1',  '5',    20240311);
INSERT INTO SERVICE (NBR,   LINE,   PAID,   DIV,    MODEL,  YMD) values ('601', '1',    'NY',   'ZZ1',  '7',    20240311);



INSERT INTO PROCESS (NBR,   DIV,    CAR,    BANK,   UNIT,   PAID) values ('555','AR91','M','1','MC','NY');
INSERT INTO PROCESS (NBR,   DIV,    CAR,    BANK,   UNIT,   PAID) values ('556','AR91','M','1','MC','NY');
INSERT INTO PROCESS (NBR,   DIV,    CAR,    BANK,   UNIT,   PAID) values ('557','AR10','M','1','MC','NY');
INSERT INTO PROCESS (NBR,   DIV,    CAR,    BANK,   UNIT,   PAID) values ('600','ZZ1','M','1','MC','NY');
INSERT INTO PROCESS (NBR,   DIV,    CAR,    BANK,   UNIT,   PAID) values ('601','ZZ1','M','1','MC','NY');
```

I want to filter out records from "Service" table so that if any "NBR" has a "DIV" matching the following, it will not be included:
('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12')

I want the results of my query to be:

```
NBR  |  MODEL
600      5
601      7
```

This is my attempt but it is still returning records that have a matching "DIV":

```
select distinct
        s.nbr,
        s.model
 from
        process p
        left outer join service s on p.nbr = s.nbr
 where
        p.unit = 'MC' and p.car = 'M' and p.bank = '1'
        and p.paid in ('NY', 'NJ')
        and s.paid = 'NY' and length(s.ymd) = 8 and s.ymd between to_number('20240303', '99999999') and to_number( '20240311', '99999999')
 AND not exists (select 1 from service s2 where s2.div IN ('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12') and s2.nbr = s.nbr )
```

Comment: Please don’t use images, as no-one can copy your data if they want to try a solution. Use editable text formatted appropriately

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (that we can copy/paste and execute and not images, which we can't).

Comment: In your `not exists` clause, `where s.div IN` should be `where s2.div IN`, so this is really just a typo (though there may be other, possibly better, ways to achieve the result you want). (Also as an aside - why are you doing `to_number('20240303', '99999999')` instead of just using an actual number `20240303`; and why are you storing dates as numbers at all?)

Comment: @MT0 I have made the edit

Comment: @AlexPoole yes you're right, to_number() is redundant. As far as why is the date stored like that, well that's not my decision.

Comment: @NickW I have fixed it with ````Create table```` and ````Insert```` statements

Comment: @H22 - you have now modified the code in your question to change `s.div` to `s2.div`. That means the code posted at the moment works as you want and just gives your two expected rows as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an analytic function and conditional aggregation to count the number of invalid div's and exclude those:

```sql
SELECT s.nbr,
       s.model
FROM   process p
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT s.*,
                  COUNT(
                    CASE
                    WHEN s.div IN ('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12')
                    THEN 1
                    END
                  ) OVER (PARTITION BY s.nbr) AS num_div
           FROM   service s
         )
         WHERE  num_div = 0
       ) s
       ON p.nbr = s.nbr
WHERE  p.unit = 'MC'
AND    p.car = 'M'
AND    p.bank = '1'
AND    p.paid in ('NY', 'NJ')
AND    s.paid = 'NY'
AND    TO_DATE(s.ymd DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'YYYYMMDD')
         BETWEEN DATE '2024-03-03' AND DATE '2024-03-11'
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| NBR | MODEL |
| --- | --- |
| 600 | 5 |
| 601 | 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5miYMr0x)

Comment: @H22 Fixed and updated for your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

One option to "filter out" NBRs having one of listed DIVs is to Inner Join a subquery fetching just the NBRs without listed DIVs. If there is a possibility of having same NBR with listed and not listed DIV in SERVICE table - filter them out with where close. If you need to implement additional conditions on columns from PROCESS table then join it too... OR do the filtering in the subquery if it is appropriate
SQL resulting as asked with the data provided could be:

```sql
Select    s.NBR, s.MODEL 
From      SERVICE s
Inner Join (  Select    NBR 
              From      PROCESS
              Where     DIV NOT IN('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12')
              Group By  NBR
           ) n ON(n.NBR = s.NBR)
Inner Join PROCESS p ON(p.NBR = n.NBR)    -- for adding conditions on PROCESS table columns
Where      
      s.DIV NOT IN('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12')  -- not needed if there are no rows with listed and not listed DIV per NBR
```

```sql
/*  Result:
NBR MODEL
--- -----
600 5
601 7     */
```

... for additional filterings - below you can see all the data from both tables for NBRs selected...

```sql
Select    s.*, ' <-- SERVICE **** PROCESS --> ' "SOURCE_TABLE_DATA", p.* 
From      SERVICE s
Inner Join (  Select    NBR 
              From      PROCESS
              Where     DIV NOT IN('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12')
              Group By  NBR
           ) n ON(n.NBR = s.NBR)
Inner Join PROCESS p ON(p.NBR = n.NBR)
Where      s.DIV NOT IN('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12')
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
DIV  PAID NBR MODEL LINE        YMD SOURCE_TABLE_DATA              DIV_1  PAID_1 NBR_1 BANK UNIT CAR
---- ---- --- ----- ---- ---------- ------------------------------ -----  ------ ----- ---- ---- ---
ZZ1  NY   600 5     1      20240311  <-- SERVICE **** PROCESS -->  ZZ1    NY     600   1    MC   M 
ZZ1  NY   601 7     1      20240311  <-- SERVICE **** PROCESS -->  ZZ1    NY     601   1    MC   M   */
```

... so you can add any other filter to get what you realy need

Comment: The OP's requirement is "I want to filter out records from `Service` table so that if any `NBR` has a `DIV` matching the following, it will not be included: `('AR91', 'AR10', 'AG55', 'AZ56', 'CZ12')`" You are filtering on the `Process` table in the second join and not the `Service` table. If you change the sample data for the `Process` table then your query does not give the expected result [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ldBztZ-).

Comment: @MTO First - the title asks for filter with join 1 to many. Maybe I'm wrong but that is how I see it and OP is the one to say if it suits him or not. Second, this is flexible enough to be easily adjusted to various possible data structures/joins/conditions some of witch I explained in tekst and commented in code. This code can do DIV filtering in one or both tables and I intentionaly omited other where conditions for they are useless with sample data provided. The whole thing is not exact, thouugh.